# Is there a method to get the current subdomain in Capybara/Selenium/Rspec?

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm testing Capybara and i need to know my current subdomain, for exemple if I'm in the url "http://mysubdomain.192.168.0.25.xip.io:3001/" i want to get the subdomain "mysubdomain". So i want to know if Capybara, Selenium or Rspec already have a method for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer:  Capybara provides `current_url` which returns the current url. You can parse that and then split the hostname on the '.'s.

```
URI.parse(current_url).hostname.split('.')[0]
```